# EF Core throws an exception when SaveChanges method is called

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

(I apologize for my English)

**UPDATE**
Well, now I'm feeling so dumb, I Forgot install the package of

> Microsoft.Entityframeworkcore.tools

In my console app Project. I install the package and it run correctly. I don't know if this can be helpful for someone but I'll let the post open. Saludos!!!

---

I'm doing some tests with Entity Framework Core in a .Net Framework console application. I have my solution split into three projects: one for my models, one for my data context and one for the console app.

I'm using Mysql server for database, and create the database with migrations so easily but when I'm trying to insert some data in the database, when I call the `SaveChanges` method, my app throws an exception.

I need to build an enterprise app, and I need to migrate the existing database (`.dbf`) to a Mysql. I'm trying to use EF Core in a console application in which and doing some tests.

> Disposing transaction.
>   Closing connection to database 'EntityFrameworkCore' on server 'localhost'.
>   Closed connection to database 'EntityFrameworkCore' on server 'localhost'.
>
> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'EntityFrameworkCore.Data.TiendaContext'.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.**DbUpdateException**:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> System.MissingFieldException: Campo no encontrado: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.ThrowReadValueExceptionMethod'.

This is my program class

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertCliente();
        }

        private static void InsertCliente()
        {
            using (var ctx = new TiendaContext())
            {
                var cliente = new Cliente { Nombre = "Pedro" };
                ctx.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());
                ctx.Clientes.Add(cliente);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

My `DbContext` class

```
public class TiendaContext:DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaccion> Trasacciones { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductosTransacciones>() 
                .HasKey(k => new { k.ProductoId, k.TransaccionId });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(
                "server=localhost;port=3306;database=EntityFrameworkCore;uid=root;password=408792");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception you are reporting it appears the entity you are trying to save; doesnt match the database structure. Compare the entities to the tables to make sure they match.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it is the same structure, I just created the db for a migration using the same solution, after that I added a new ConsoleApp project and I set the code like I posted and it's not working :(...

Answer (score -1):

You should update your ef core nuget package. After that, hope error will gone